# Rspec: Run specific unit test on every model unless whitelisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant SaaS app.  I run a tenant security test on every tenant model.

```
describe 'tenant security' do
  it "has only the current company's data" do
    set_tenant_company
    other_companys_data = create :model

    set_tenant_company
    this_companys_data = create :model

    expect(Model.all).to include this_companys_data
    expect(Model.all).not_to include other_companys_data
  end
end
```

Is there a way to use meta programming to run this on every model? [Without explicitly coding anything into the unit test]  If so, is there a way to whitelist non-tenant models?

Tenant security is critical, and I don't want it inadvertantly overlooked.

Comment: I don't know how to do it automatically unless whitelisted, but you could use `behaves_like` as it only needs one implementation and a few lines on every tenant model. Take a look at this: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: Thank you!  Shared_examples seems better that what I am doing.  Is there a way to have a shared_example run once automatically for each model spec file?  Is there a way to tell it to skip a certain file (whitelist)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on Pedro's comments, and his question posted to the RSpec core team:

Create a shared example with test you want to implicitly include in each model.  The :unless condition is for white-listing models that should not include this test.

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'a tenant model' do
  it "has only the current company's data",unless: metadata[:not_a_tenant_model] == true do
    set_tenant_company
    other_companys_data = create subject.class.name.underscore.to_sym

    set_tenant_company
    this_companys_data = create subject.class.name.underscore.to_sym

    expect(subject.class.all).to include this_companys_data
    expect(subject.class.all).not_to include other_companys_data
  end
end
```

Place the following line in your RSpec.configuration

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include_context 'a tenant model', type: :model
end
```

This has the effect of placing the following in every model.

```
Rspec.describe TenantModel do
  it_behaves_like 'a tenant model'
end
```

To whitelist a non-tenant model, just add the appropriate tag:

```
RSpec.decribe NonTenantModel, :not_a_tenant_model do
  # shared example will not be included
end
```

Big thank you! to Pedro and the RSpec core team.

Comment: After some research and test, I believe it is not possible because you can't generate examples at runtime. RSpec doesn't allow you to do this. Anyway, I asked the core team if any way to do this exists here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2480 If there is way, it would be as easy as create an array and check for presence of described class in it.

Comment: Thank you!  I am also looking at [Metadata](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata), [Filtering](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/filtering), and [after(:context) hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks).  I haven't landed on a working solution for conditionally running the shared_examples yet.

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted solution needs to tag specificly every non-tenant model. With this solution, you do this in the configuration.

Well, thanks to opening this issue: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2480, This seems to be the very best solution for your case:

```
non_tenant_models = %w(NonTenantModelOne NonTenantModelTwo).map(&:constantize)

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.define_derived_metadata(type: :model) do |meta|
    meta[:tenant_model] = true unless meta[:described_class].presence_in non_tenant_models
  end

  c.include_context "shared", tenant_model: true
end
```

This gives you clear metadata saying if the model is tenant, and whitelists every non-tenant model specified of running shared examples, without need to code anything in the models.

Comment: Very nice abstraction of the 'whitelist' tag into the configuration.  In my specific case, I prefer to have the whitelisting tag explicitly placed in the whitelisted specs.  While I want to ensure this test is included in every model, I like to keep my tests as explicit as possible.  Thanks for all your input.  I coudn't have implemented the solution without your help.